# Open an external PDF at the specific section in a new tab

Tags: pdftex, pdf, href

I want to hyperlink to an external pdf file at the specific section. I have a solution to open the file on a specific page but not at the specific section.

Next problem Im facing is that every time new document opens, it closes the previous one. (Im using Linux system and Okular for pdf-but I have tried other pdf readers too).

My goal: hyperlink to external pdf - specific section in a new tab.

Thank you a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href[section=intro]{../PU.xxxx.pdf}{text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it depends on the external pdf. If it has anchors at the sections you can use them if there are not anchors you can only link to the pages.

Comment: They are both created with Kile-latex and they both have anchors (if you mean labels?), but it does not recognize them, IDK why. What about a solution for opening a pdf in a new tab? It is a problem because it closes the previous pdf..

Comment: try with `\href{../PU.xxxx.pdf#section.1}{text}`, and I have no idea about linux, I'm on windows.

Comment: It works, thank you. What about subsection? #section.1.2 not working..

Comment: I got it.. \href{../PU.xxxx.pdf#subsection.1.1}{text}

Answer (score 1):

Žan
You asked:

> What about a solution for opening a pdf in a new tab?

I found that [pdfnewwindow] as an optional parameter to \href gives the desred result.

\href{../PU.xxxx.pdf#section.1}{text}

becomes:

\href[pdfnewwindow]{../PU.xxxx.pdf#section.1}{text}